# Proving a distribution is normal with only one moment (Stein's method)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, analysis, statistics

So my question is essentially - if we have a random variable $X$ which appears to follow a normal distribution, and we have access to solely its first moment, is there any other information which would allow us to prove it indeed has a normal distribution? Generally speaking, what ways are there to determine a normal distribution? For instance, if we computed the MGF, or if we proved each moment was the same as that of a normal distribution (the latter is the one most aligned to my interests- what if we cannot find each moment but we had some other information which meant solely knowing the first moment was sufficient).

How would one apply Stein's method to a specific random variable $X$, given knowledge of the first moment, to determine whether it followed a normal distribution?

Comment: Showing the moments agree would be the same as computing the MGF. Note that this works here since the MGF does exist. In general, if the MGF does not exist, then all moments agreeing implies nothing about the two distributions being equal.

Comment: What do you mean by "appears to follow a normal distribution"?

Comment: Since normal distributions can have any finite first moment, knowing the first moment does not help with the shape of the distribution beyond excluding those without a finite first moment